# Ubuntu 11.04 Laptop Screen not working

Tags: 11.04, laptop, monitor

Just installed Ubuntu 11.04 and my Laptop screen has stopped working, although an external monitor still works fine.
It won't even display the bios.

It stopped working during a debian upgrade (yesterday), so I installed ubuntu hoping it would fix it.

It is an Asus with an ATI chip, the only thing I have tried is installing the fglrx drivers, but they are causing a kernel panic, and I have as of yet been unable to get it to boot without quiet or splash.

```
root@fluffie:/home/chris# lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge [1022:9600]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (int gfx) [1022:9602]
00:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0) [1022:9603]
00:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1) [1022:9605]
00:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2) [1022:9606]
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1002:4391]
00:12.0 USB Controller [0c03]: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
00:12.1 USB Controller [0c03]: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller [1002:4398]
00:12.2 USB Controller [0c03]: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
00:13.0 USB Controller [0c03]: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
00:13.1 USB Controller [0c03]: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller [1002:4398]
00:13.2 USB Controller [0c03]: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 SMBus Controller [1002:4385] (rev 3a)
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) [1002:4383]
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller [1002:439d]
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge [1002:4384]
00:14.5 USB Controller [0c03]: ATI Technologies Inc SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller [1002:4399]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 11h Processor HyperTransport Configuration [1022:1300] (rev 40)
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 11h Processor Address Map [1022:1301]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 11h Processor DRAM Controller [1022:1302]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 11h Processor Miscellaneous Control [1022:1303]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 11h Processor Link Control [1022:1304]
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc RS780M/RS780MN [Radeon HD 3200 Graphics] [1002:9612]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ATI Technologies Inc M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500 Series] [1002:9553]
02:00.1 Audio device [0403]: ATI Technologies Inc RV710/730 [1002:aa38]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
```

[Xorg.log](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/830512/)

And apparently xorg.conf doesn't exist anymore.

I apologize for not posting this earlier, I've never had a main monitor issue like this so I was unsure what would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

this smells like hardware problem. The motherboard and graphic card should be fine, as the external monitor is working. It cant be a driver issue as not even the bios is displayed. Either the screen is broken or it is a cable issue. Good luck.

Comment: was afraid that would be an answer.  It broke on a reboot and the screen wasn't jarred at all so I was hoping for something else.  I guess ill take the screen off and check the connection.  Thanks